# Youtube Live API - Broadcast premission denied using OAuth

Tags: c#, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, google-api-dotnet-client, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am trying to broadcast live from my .Net application using Youtube.Data.Api v3. 
I have set up OAuth and downloaded the .JSON file, and that works fine. I know that, because I have already successfully obtained a list of channels resp. videos on my account, i.e., following code works:

```
var channelsRequest = ytService.Channels.List("contentDetails, snippet");
channelsRequest.Mine = true;
var channelsListResponse = channelsRequest.Execute();
```

But if I try to execute a insert request (for completeness I show you the whole method),

```
public static LiveBroadcast CreateImmediateBroadcast(string title = "DefaultBroadcast") {
    var snippet = new LiveBroadcastSnippet();
    snippet.Title = title;
    snippet.ScheduledStartTime = DateTime.Now;
    snippet.ScheduledEndTime = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);

    var status = new LiveBroadcastStatus();
    status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted";

    var broadcast = new LiveBroadcast();
    broadcast.Kind = "youtube#liveBroadcast";
    broadcast.Snippet = snippet;
    broadcast.Status = status;

    var insertBroadcastRequest = ytService.LiveBroadcasts.Insert(broadcast, "snippet, status");
    insertBroadcastRequest.Execute();
    return broadcast;
}
```

I get an exception when calling `insertBroadcastRequest.Execute()`, namely:

> Google.GoogleApiException was unhandled
>
> HResult=-2146233088
>     Message=Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
>
> Insufficient Permission [403]
>   Errors [
>       Message[Insufficient Permission] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]
>   ]
>   ServiceName=youtube
>
> Source=Google.Apis
>
> StackTrace:
>          at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute() in C:\Users\cloudsharp\Documents\GitHub\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\Support\GoogleApis\Apis\Requests\ClientServiceRequest.cs:line 96
>          at YoutubeConsole.YouTubeAPI.CreateImmediateStream(String title) in C:\Users\bussg\Source\Workspaces\OwnExperimental\YoutubeConsole\YoutubeConsole\YouTubeAPI.cs:line 87
>          at YoutubeConsole.YouTubeAPI.Test() in 
>   ...

Also, for completeness, here is my authorization,

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\GoogleAuthOtherApplication.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeForceSsl},
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore("YouTubeAPI")
    ).Result;
}
```

Also, For the `YouTubeService.Scope` I have tried all options. The `insert` method should work with `ForceSsl` according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert).

Also [this documentation page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/authentication) sais

> Note: A channel must be approved to use the YouTube Live feature, which enables the channel owner to stream live content to that channel. If you send API requests on behalf of an authenticated user whose channel is not enabled or eligible to stream live content, the API will return an insufficientPermissions error.

But all my channels are approved for Youtube Live. Any ideas how to get this to work?

Comment: Wild guess you probably have to be a  YouTube Content Partner. or maybe this https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2474026?hl=en

Comment: @DalmTo: I have crawled through many of the documentation pages already multiple times, and nowhere do they mention having to be content partner (that you ony need if you want to show advertisement in your stream. And concerning your link: Also checked that, my channel is elegible for live treaming without restrictions.

Comment: Where are you in the world?

Comment: @DalmTo: in Leipzig, Germany. Why?

Comment: Domain[global] makes me wonder if its a location discrimination thing.  I have never tried live streaming but I could test your code from Denmark see if I get the same thing.

Comment: @DalmTo: Sure, that would be great. Can I reach you privately somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after some testing between us over Email.

1. You need to have the correct scope "YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeForceSsl" by changing "user" we forced it to request permissions again. My [tutorial](http://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/) on how filedata store works in the Google .net client library
2. remove the space "snippet, status" by sending "snippet,status" it worked for me.

For the fun of it:  [Issue 8568:LiveBroadcasts: insert - spaces in part](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=8568)

Comment: Thanks! Let me add the following: "status" and "snippet" don't work on their own. Only a request containing "status" AND "snippet" (and possibly more strings), and no spaces, works.

Comment: Also a similar issue will come up for the `livestreams.insert` request. There it is necessary to include "snippet" AND "cdn" as part parameters in the request.

Comment: Thanks for letting me play with a new API :)